# ViewController won't update after load

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I got two viewControllers using a navigation bar. The first viewController displays some data I change on the second viewController.

So if I load the second viewController, a back button appears in the NavBar and I can change my values (and they **are** stored, I used the debugger). My problem is, after hitting the backButton to come to my firstView Controller, it does not call it's `viewDidLoad` method. It's clear, that there are no updated values at all, when this function is not called.

At the first start, the `viewDidLoad` method is called and does what I want it to do. After going back and forth between the viewControllers the method is not called again.

Any solutions?

Thanks!

EDIT:

**SOLVED**

I did not want to delete my question, maybe someone needs this too:

This method is called every time the view appears, it is probably not defined by default:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSLog(@"View appeared.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But the update code (like `[[self view] setNeedsDisplay];`) in `viewWillAppear`.

To make it clear: `viewDidLoad` is called when your view is loaded. This happens at the first time the view is going to be displayed. When you then navigate to the next view the first view can (depending on your code) still be loaded. Therefore when you navigate back to that view `viewDidLoad` won't be called because the view is still there.

But every time the view is going to be shown (for example when you navigate back to this view) the method `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` will be called.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewDidLoad` method will get called when there is view controller allocation-initialization happens. In the case of moving back in navigation controller, it is not creating any new view controllers, it is reusing previous references from navigation stack.

Hence `viewDidLoad` will not get called. As your view controller is already in memory stack. So it will just make the view to reappear on windows and it will call `viewWillAppear` respectively.